# Why does "Range(...).End(xlDown).Row" return 1048576?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy some values in a for-loop in VBA. Therefore I calculate the limits by:

```
For iCounter = 1 To (Range(...).End(xlDown).Row - Range(...).Row  + 1)
```

Sadly `Range(...).End(xlDown).Row` returns `1048576`. When I debug, suddenly the value changes to the right one. The same Code works well in some other locations in the VBA Code.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing to keep in mind is that the `End` method reproduces in VBA the functionality of using Ctrl+Arrow Keys. These are meant to navigate between blocks of values.

Start at A1 here:

[image]

Hit `Ctrl+Down`:

[image]

This illustrates what happens when you use `Ctrl+Down` at the beginning or end of a block consisting of multiple cells -- you go to the end of that block. This is the case that you are implicitly referring to when you said that sometimes the code works well.

Now -- hit `Ctrl+Down` again:

[image]

You jumped to the next block. Now, do it again:

[image]

The bottom of that block. Finally, again:

[image]

Well -- there is no next block to go to -- so it goes all the way down. This corresponds to the case that strikes you as weird. It puts you here:

[image]

But -- something cool happens now: Press `Ctrl + Up` -- and Excel searches *up* for the next block:

[image]

And *this* is the last cell with data in column A.

For this reason -- you see the following code a lot in Excel VBA:

```
Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)
```

To get the last used cell in a column (1 in this case) or the first cell in the column if the overall column is blank.

Comment: Nicely said!  OP, note this is also how `.End(xlDown)`, `,.End(xlToRight)`, and `.End(xlToLeft)` work.

Answer (score 1):

Very very old question. but may help someone. the answer for the initial question "Range(...).End(xlDown).Row returns 1048576" is as follows:

The Range should have the Sheet name. Ex., Worksheets("MySheetName").Range(...).End(xlDown).Row

This is why its working in Debug mode but not when ran the VBA macro. Again, the result value may differ based on gaps between the data. I had the same problem and realized this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's curious what you're saying about getting the right value when debugging.  That makes me think that you may need to show more of your code.  Anyway, doesn't matter, I just decided to have some fun with this.  Here are multiple sample code snippets to do what you're asking about.  Hope it gives you or anyone else interested some ideas about how to approach this problem because it is very common.

I'd definitely avoid using End(xlwhatever) on its own. It makes for non-robust code because it's too easy for values to get shuffled. It's not hard to just take the time to create a more elegant solution. You should be able to come up with something pretty robust by tailoring and combining the methods below for your particular use.

```
Sub CellLoop1()
    'Colors cells from row i to last value in column
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    Next
End Sub
Sub CellLoop2()
    'Colors cells from row i to end of continuous values or until row 100
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells(i, 1)
        Do Until r.Value2 = "" Or i > 100
            r.Interior.Color = 123
            i = i + 1
            Set r = Cells(i, 1)
        Loop
End Sub
Sub CellLoop3()
    'Colors cells from row i until occurance of 5 continuous blanks
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells(i, 1)
    Dim BlankChain As Integer
    Do Until BlankChain >= 5
        r.Interior.Color = 123
        If r.Value = Empty Then
            BlankChain = BlankChain + 1
        Else
            BlankChain = 0
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Set r = Cells(i, 1)
    Loop
End Sub
Sub CellLoop4()
    'Colors cells from row i until no value in sight (in next k number of rows)
    Dim i, k, BlankCount As Integer
    i = 1
    k = 10
    Dim r, SightRange As Range
    Set r = Cells(i, 1)
    Dim NoValueInSight As Boolean: NoValueInSight = False
    Do Until NoValueInSight
        Set SightRange = Range(r, r.Offset(k - 1, 0))
        BlankCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(SightRange)
        If BlankCount = SightRange.Rows.Count Then
            NoValueInSight = True
        Else
            r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 50, 255)
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Set r = Cells(i, 1)
    Loop
End Sub
Sub CellLoop5()
    'Colors all values under range r (set as "A1")
    Dim r, UnderRange As Range
    Set r = Range("A3")
    Set UnderRange = Range(r, Cells(Rows.Count, 1))
    Dim i, n, BlankCount As Double: i = r.Row: n = 0
    BlankCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(UnderRange)
    Do Until n = (UnderRange.Rows.Count - BlankCount)
        If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
Sub CellLoop6()
    'Colors all values under range r (set as "A1")
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    If r.Value = "" Then Set r = r.End(xlDown)
    Do Until r.Value = ""
        r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 100, 100)
        If r.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
            For i = r.Row To r.End(xlDown).Row
                Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 100, 100)
            Next
        End If
        Set r = r.End(xlDown)
    Loop
End Sub
```