# Stopping a macro from pasting all over the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been beating my head against this for 2 days now. I am trying to get this code to copy a limited range from sheet 1 and paste it into sheet 2 starting at a specific cell. Then have it go back and paste another value from sheet 1 into the blank spaces but stopping at the last blank spot in the copied values, but not below it. What is happening is that the first part is working as intended, but the second is filling the entire page or filling every cell below the pasted information with what I am trying to place into the blank cells. Also bonus points if you can get the first parts range to be dynamic, but I'm sure I can figure that out myself.

```
Sub Export()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2:A50").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("L2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C50").End(xlDown).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I am very much a novice at this so I'm sure that it is just something I don't know yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192372/why-does-range-endxldown-row-return-1048576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but I think it will work:

```
Sub Export()
    Dim cell as Range
    Dim x as integer
    Dim s as string
    s = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2").Value
    x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & x).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C" & x)
        If cell.value = "" Then
            cell.Value = s
        End If
    Next
    CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This performed the pasting of the first column without issue, but did not paste the "L2" into the blank cells. I like how much cleaner this code is though. I know mine probably looks like a garbled mess.

Comment: You have to start somewhere with the respect to the code itself. :)  As for the copy/paste issue, I did end up testing this just now, and it worked for me... You only want to fill in blank cells in the `Sheet2.Range("C3:C50")` area correct?

Comment: I think what is happening is that I'm so new to this that I am not explaining it right. There is information in Column A Sheet 1 that needs to be moved over to Column C Sheet 2. Now, that information changes with every export and how many rows are filled and also where the blanks are. So I am trying to build this macro using a set range first and was going to worry about dynamic selection after it was working for the most part, but looks like this is probably causing the issue.

Comment: See my edited code above for a more dynamic approach.

Comment: I owe you a beer my friend! Worked perfectly! That did it, thanks for helping out a novice. Now I just need to break it down so I can understand what you did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After deleting all your select statements (The macro recorder does this, but its really not necessary) We can look at your code a little clearer...

```
Sub Export()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A50").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Paste

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2").Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C50").End(xlDown).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Paste
End Sub
```

But I think the simplest code you can make for what you want to do is

```
Sub Export()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C52") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50").Value
    On Error Resume Next ' Required because an error is thrown when there are no blanks.
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C52").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: or even a bit shorter without error checking `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3:C52").Replace "", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2")`

Comment: The second one is very close, but it continues filling in the L2 after the information from the other sheet. It did stop filling in the rest of the spreadsheet and did limit the fill to just the one column.

Comment: "after the information from the other sheet" --- well yes, you need to shorten C3:C50 to your data set... which is the dynamic part you said you'd handle!

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is the short version :]

```
Sub Export()
    [Sheet2!C3:C52] = [Sheet1!A1:A50].Value
    Range([Sheet2!C3], [Sheet2!C53].End(xlUp)).Replace "", [Sheet1!L2]
End Sub
```

Comment: @Cody G. .. well it can if it is run from Sheet1 or Sheet2, or if the CodeNames of the sheets are renamed :]