# Go to last non-blank row in excel

Tags: excel, vba, range

Dears,

I was thinking the below codes would bring me to the last non-bank row in a column:

```
Sub commandtryanderror()
    Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select
End Sub
```

However, I found if there is only the cell `A1` has content, the above codes would bring me to the end row in excel, that is row number `1048576` but if there are contents in cell `A2` and `A3`, the above codes will bring me to `A3`, and that is what I want, can you tell me why and how should I correct the program?  Thanks.

Comment: Either you can check if the current row is 1048576 after `Select` or check if A2 has any value followed by `Select`.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. It checks if your macro would send you to the bottom of the sheet. If that is the case it will send you to cell A1.

```
Sub find_last_cell()

If Range("A1").End(xlDown) = Range("A1048576") _
    Then
    Range("A1").Select
Else
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
End If

End Sub
```

Do note, if there is a gap in your data, it will not pass the data. If this is a problem you can convert the macro to search from the bottom up.

Comment: Yes, i tried and it works, but could you tell me why such phenomena happen in my original codes?  I always think the command end(Xldown) will bring me to the last non-blank row, why it go to the row 1048576 instead, but it works normal when cell "a2" has contents....

Comment: I have just found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192372/why-does-range-endxldown-row-return-1048576
It seems that is the answer...Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm. If you want to see the effect of ```end(x1[Direction]```, use [ctrl] + [direction arrow]. If there are no cells with data between the selected cell and the edge of the document, you will jump to the edge.